# What exactly should I be returning in this code?

Tags: java, arrays, return

We are creating a program that will return a topographic map and show the user the best way to navigate the terrain without making steep climbs or descents. For the files that I am working with, I am not sure what maximum and minimum values need to be returned. The assignment is mostly complete except for 3 errors regarding an expected return value. I've submitted the primary code that we are working with and included a link to the other files the professor has given us for the assignment.

**I've tried return maxValue, return minValue, return max, return min, and a few other combinations but the issue is I'm not sure if I am supposed to be returning a value from this MapDataDrawer.java file or from one of the other two files that we have to use for the assignment from the professor.**

```
//MapDataDrawer.java
//This is the code that is returning the error
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MapDataDrawer
{

  private int[][] grid;

  public MapDataDrawer(String filename, int rows, int cols){
      // initialize grid 
      grid = new int[rows][cols];

      //read the data from the file into the grid
      File dataFile = new File(filename);
      try {
         Scanner dataInput = new Scanner(dataFile);
         for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<cols;j++) {
               grid[i][j] = dataInput.nextInt();

            }
         }

      } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace();}

  }

  /**
   * @return the min value in the entire grid
   */
  public int findMin() {
     // Implement this method
  }
  /**
   * @return the max value in the entire grid
   */
  public int findMax(){
     // Implement this method
  }

  /**
   * @param col the column of the grid to check
   * @return the index of the row with the lowest value in the given col for the grid
   */
  public  int indexOfMinRow(int col){
     //Implement this method

  }

  /**
   * Draws the grid using the given Graphics object.
   * Colors should be grayscale values 0-255, scaled based on min/max values in grid
   */
  public void drawMap(Graphics g){
      int min = findMin();
      int max = findMax();

      for (int i=0; i<480; i++) {
         for (int j=0; j<480; j++) {
            int c = (255 * (grid[i][j] - min)) / (max - min);
            g.setColor(new Color(c, c, c));
            g.fillRect(j, i, 1, 1);
         }
      }
   }

   /**
   * Find a path from West-to-East starting at given row.
   * Choose a foward step out of 3 possible forward locations, using greedy method described in assignment.
   * @return the total change in elevation traveled from West-to-East
   */
  public int drawLowestElevPath(Graphics g, int row){
    int elevChange = 0;
      // Implement this method
      return elevChange;

  }

   private int minOfThree(int a, int b, int c) {
      if ((a > b) && (a > c)) return a;
      if ((b > a) && (b > c)) return b;
      if ((c > a) && (c > b)) return c;
      return 0;
   }

}
```

These are the professors submitted files, of which I am unsure if I am supposed to be returning some value from one of these files or from the actual homework file (MapDataDrawer.java) https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1siRoY1K0ngptE2rL-wscXLK8Ct7Qo1hb?usp=sharing

It also includes the topographic data we are supposed to use.

Comment: Please describe what you have already tried and try to ask a specific question. Currently you're asking the community to identify and solve your homework.

Comment: Looks like you need to at least implement methods `findMin`, `findMax`, and `indexOfMinRow`, which should not be too hard.

Comment: I can't see anything highlighted in bold. It would be more helpful if you told us the actual error messages and the lines that they are associated with. But I'd guess you have compile errors because the findMin(), findMax() and indexOfMinRow() methods have a return type (int) but don't actually return a value.

Comment: Now, I guess you're really asking us _what_ you should return in those fields? The only answer we can really give is "an appropriate value". We don't necessarily know the maths or logic behind this to know what the correct answer is. This seems to be a more a question about the logic of your algorithm than a technical issue with the code. If you're not sure what the intent of the homework is, ask your professor.

Comment: This is the error I am receiving: MapDataDrawer.java:34: error: missing return statement
  }
  ^
MapDataDrawer.java:40: error: missing return statement
  }
  ^
MapDataDrawer.java:49: error: missing return statement
  }
  ^
3 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.

Comment: From what I understand I am supposed to be returning the values from findMin, findMax and indexOfMinRow, but not sure how to return those in the file. I just attempted return Min; return Max and return indexOfMinRow[]; under the lines that indicated errors but it is not finding those values for the variables which is leading me to think the values we need to return are in one or both of the other files the professor submitted.

Comment: " I am supposed to be returning the values from findMin, findMax and indexOfMinRow,"...your statement doesn't make sense. Those methods don't yet _have_ any value because you haven't implemented any code inside them to produce a value. There's nothing to return. Simply writing `return min;` doesn't work because there's no such variable called `min` yet. `int min = 1; return min;` would work, but obviously doesn't actually do anything useful, it just returns the same thing every time.

Comment: Correct. Another user highlighted that in an answer and I was able to complete the rest of the assignment on my own. The issue was I was so worried about using the other files (first assignment where we are working with multiple files in coding) that I was afraid that we would have to call on code from those files.

Comment: Presumably you have to return the result of a calculation, but what that calculation actually is, is not for us to say - that's down to whatever logic your work is supposed to be implementing.

Comment: Ok. Glad you were able to sort it out. Calling code from other files is not really an "issue", it's a common part of programming, btw. Whether that was the right thing to do in order to solve the problem, would have been down to you to decide, I guess.

Comment: The "issue" being I wasn't sure if the max or min values were already defined and calculated in one of the other files that we were given. If I would have just continued making the method on my own as we did in the other assignments I would have been just fine. I was just over thinking and making the assignment A LOT harder than it has to be. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have filled `grid`:

```
public int findMin() {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
           int value = grid[i][j];
           if (value < min) {
               min = value;
           }
        }
     }
     return min;
 }
```

Comment: This was very helpful! I was missing code that actually told the program WHAT to return with an if statement. I think I can do the rest based on this example.